# Web Audio API with SpiderMonkey?

Tags: web-audio-api, spidermonkey

Is it possible to use the Web Audio API with SpiderMonkey or other standalone JavaScript engines? - V8 doesn't seem to support it.

Asking because I'm currently rendering audio artifacts in the browser with the Web Audio API, using `OfflineAudioContext`, but would like to perform that task in other contexts, outside the browser environment.

(A related question is: Can the WebGL canvas be accessed from a standalone JavaScript engine such as SpiderMonkey?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Audio API is a browser API and not a JavaScript feature. Therefore it's missing in SpiderMonkey or V8.

However there are some projects like [audiojs/web-audio-api](https://github.com/audiojs/web-audio-api) which allow you to use the same API (or parts of it) with Node.js.

There is also a fork of Chromium's Web Audio API implementation called [LabSound](https://github.com/LabSound/LabSound).

And last but not least there is also a Rust implementation called [web-audio-api-rs](https://github.com/orottier/web-audio-api-rs).

If all of that doesn't work for your use case you could also run Firefox or Chrome in headless mode controlled by [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) or [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/).

Comment: Thanks @chrisguttandin for listing those options.  `web-audio-api-rs` seems to have reached furthest in implementing the API, and a related project as begun implementing JS bindings for that.  I'll do some further comparison of the options.